# Spring @Component with Parent

Tags: spring, annotations

Is there a way to define the Parent class for annotated with @Component. We are having a mix of Annotations and XML definitions

```
@Component
public class BaseClass extends SuperClass
{
}

/**
* This bean is defined in the XML and made as abstract
*/
public abstract class SuperClass extends VerySuperClass
{
}

/**
* This bean is defined in the XML and made as abstract
*/
public abstract class VerySuperClass
{
    protected IEmployeeDAO employeeDAO;
    protected ITableDAO tableDAO;
}
```

The problem here is with the Annotation and it is not inheriting its parent defined properties which are getting as null in the `BaseClass.java`.

I know that If we defined as XML bean this works, but if there is a way to say its parent through Annotation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking. Are you trying to inject bean into `employeeDAO` and `tableDAO` ? Are they annotated with `@Autowired` ?

Comment: 'VerySuperClass' bean is defined in the applicationContext as xml style bean, so its properties 'employeeDAO' and 'tableDAO' are also defined in the 'applicationContext'.

When i'm accessing the 'BaseClass', those 2 properties which are in 'VerySuperClass' should also be accessed but which it is returning as null

Comment: `VerySuperClass` cannot be a bean as it is abstract. The only bean is `BaseClass`. You need to inject `employeeDAO` and `tableDAO` into `BaseClass`

Comment: 'VerySuperClass' can be abstract bean and as i mentioned above, it is defined as XML bean and its properties are registered in the XML

Comment: Please show your declaration of VerySuperClass in XML.

Comment: Here is the code for it


<bean
 id="verySuperClass"
 abstract="true"
 class="org.com.training.VerySuperClass">
 <property name="employeeDAO" ref="employeeDAO" />
 <property name="tableDAO" ref="tableDAO" />
</bean>

Answer (score 2):

Your `VerySuperClass` should Autowire the DAOs to have those instances.

```
public abstract class VerySuperClass {

    @Autowired
    protected IEmployeeDAO employeeDAO;

    @Autowired
    protected ITableDAO tableDAO;
}
```

Now with `BaseClass` bean you can access `VerySuperClass` beans.

I have created blow example for your better understanding.

> https://github.com/avinashroy/spring.di.componentHierarchy

Comment: i have not checked with the Autowired annotation, but the DAOs are injected through XML for the 'VerySuperclass' bean. This bean is specified as abstract.
If the beans (DAOs) are injected either through XML or Annotation, it should work the same way

Comment: I have updated my answer with a working example link.